# Spring JPA copy entity to another table with the same columns

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I want to copy an entry from my table `A` to table `B`. table `A` and `B` have the same columns.

To do this I would need two Java entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class TableA{
   @Id 
   @GeneratedValue
   @SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq",sequenceName="MY_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class TableB{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;
}
```

And then map each value from `A` to `B`

```
@PreRemove
public void insertIntoB(TableA tableA) {
   TableB tableB = new TableB();
   tableB.setId(tableA.getId());
   tableBRepository.save(tableB);
}
```

This approach would be fine when Table `A` and `B` only have 1 column, but in my case I am working with 50+, so the `insertIntoB` method would be huge. Also I will have to maintain two Java entities with this approach, since if there are changes made to table `A` then those changes also have to be reflected in the table `B` entity. And `insertIntoB` would also have to be changed after every added new column to table `A`.

How can I make this solution more elegant? Is there a way to share one entity object for both tables or map the values from `A` automatically to `B`? Please consider that table `A` uses a `SequenceGenerator` while table `B` simply uses the passed `id` from table `A`.

Comment: No - Within JPA, you are dealing with Java objects, so have to find a way to copy or clone each. I'm not sure what is huge about reading in a set of As and iterating over a copy method in a loop. Streams can make it pretty, and if you put it all in one transaction with batch writing enabled, it could be issued to the DB in one insert statement. Alternatively though if yo don't want to read in all As, you can try native SQL with something similar to "INSERT INTO A (id) SELECT id FROM B WHERE ..."  do the work for you. See  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: A could have a buildB method within it, since if you change class A to add properties, you should deal with its own methods and the contracts on them at the same time. then it would be simply query.getResultList().stream().forEach(a->tableBRepository.save(a.buildB()));. Alternatively, you could build something to reflectively look at the A class, iterate over all its properties, instantiate a B instance and set all the matching B properties based solely on the property name. It can be done, but seems like much more work, effort and risk of going wrong than maintaining a copy method

Comment: If you dont need any fancy java code you could simply use an „insert into select from“ query. But you need two entities in JPA as an Entity cannot be shared. If it‘s about auditing you can check if Hibernate Envers can work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Please use Mapstruct library which is aptly suited for this job.

```
@Mapper(
    componentModel = "spring",
    nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS,
    nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
public interface AgencyLocationMapper {

  // Map table A to table B
  TableB mapToTableB(TableA tableA);

}
```

Comment: using Mapstruct is a very good idea, thank you!

Comment: Indeed, like I suggested before..

Answer (score 1):

Using an ORM, I guess I would simply make use of the standard JPA `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` annotations to reuse certain mappings that reoccur and make sense to bundle while using of course two separate entities.

You can then map the entities manually (which is my personal preference as there is nothing wrong with some manual one-time labour) or use a reflection library like [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) to try and ease the pain when mapping until it doesn't exactly do what you expect and you then spend 20 minutes debugging the thing.